# Android, Changing app language not working properly on oneplus and huawei

Tags: android, locale, android-configchanges

I am changing the app loacale like this,

```
     Language language = getPreferenceAppLanguage();
        if (language == null) {
            return;
        }

        Locale locale = createLocale(language);

        Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources res = mContext.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
            mContext.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

In every other devices it works fine , but in oneplus and huawei , when I change the language and start app again the all the resources are set to english locale only. Does anyone have a fix for this?

This does not happen when I restart the activity, only happens when I close the app and start again

Comment: what is `getPreferenceAppLanguage`

Comment: it returns language which is saved in shared preference , createLocale(language) returns locale for that language